# C does not run until I use the quit command

Tags: c, scanf

fellow programmers. I am pretty new to this area that is why I may be having my problem.

I am told to write a program that finds the area and circumference of a circle. One condition, display the output to 5 decimal places. the output should look like this.

The radius of the circle is ________.

The diameter of the circle is_______.

The area of the circle is__________.

The circumference is____________.

here is my code that I wrote for this problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        float r, area, circ, diam, pi = 3.14159;

        printf("Enter the radius please");
        scanf("%f\n", &r);

        printf("The radius of the circle is %0.5f\n", r);

        diam = 2 * r;
        printf("The diameter of the circle is %0.5f\n", diam);

        area = pi * r * r;
        printf("The area of the circle is %0.5f\n", area);

        circ = 2 * pi * r;
        printf("The circumference of the circle is %0.5f\n", circ);

        return 0;
    }
```

The code runs and showing me this in the terminal

```
Enter the radius please4
```

I placed 4 as a testing sample. This is when the program just stops working. I type `q` and hit enter. This is when the rest of the output shows up like so.

```
The radius of the circle is 4.00000
The diameter of the circle is 8.00000
The area of the circle is 50.26544
The circumference of the circle is 25.13272
```

Comment: Did you hit return after entering the 4? If not, there's no way for the program to know if you're done entering a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Najik,
Are you sure that you want to have a "\n" in the scanf ?
I think for what you want you need to remove it.
Before:

```
scanf("%f\n", &r);
```

After:

```
scanf("%f", &r);
```

This will ensure the scanf function is finished shortly after entering the number and pressing Enter.

Hope I had help you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `scanf` format string:

```
scanf("%f\n", &r);
```

By putting `\n` in the format string, it consumes any newline character that you enter and waits for a character that isn't a newline.

Remove `\n` from the format specifier and it will work as expected:

```
scanf("%f", &r);
```

Comment: Not just any newline character. Any whitespace in the format string (such as a space or a newline) consumes any amount of any whitespace in the input.